# Getting "no join predicate" warning even tho I am using "inner join"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL server 2008 R2 and I have a query that inner joins 3 tables:

```
select * from  t1 INNER JOIN t2 on t1."Account Key" = t2."Account Key"
INNER JOIN t3 on t2."Account Key" = t3."Account Key"
```

The problem is that I am getting a "no join predicate" warning on the second inner join; in addition to that, it is doing cross product of the table produced by the 1st join with t3 which makes the query run forever (besides giving the wrong results).

I ran the following query to see if there are any account keys equal on both sides of the last join:

```
select "Account Key" from  t1 INNER JOIN t2 on t1."Account Key" = t2."Account Key"
INTERSECT 
select "Account Key" from t3 on t2."Account Key" = t3."Account Key"
```

I get 0 rows, which means that there are no account keys equal on on both sides of the join. However, **should not the original query give 0 rows instead of giving a cross product since I am using an "inner join"?**

**Update**: The t3 is acutally a view whose [Account Key] column is actually a calculated column:

```
CAST(bid AS varchar(5)) + '-' + dbo.ConvertNumericToPaddedChar(RMKEY, 20) AS [Account Key]
```

**Update**: the dbo.ConvertNumericToPaddedChar(RMKEY, 20) is what causing the problem. It seems that when doing inner joins,  SQL Server can't use columns that were built using user-defined functions.

Do any of you know any way around this?

Comment: Have you tried after removing the "" from the join columns? I am not quite sure if you can specify columns in a join that way. Other than that, the query seems absolutely fine to me

Comment: @In Sane: Exactly my thought, but instead of removing the double quotes, replace them with square brackets, like `[Account Key]`.  OR run `set quoted identifier on`; that explicitly allows the double quotes

Comment: @Andomar - aha!! there is a space in the column name!! Just so not used to expecting those that my eyes just completely missed it!! :-) Good catch there!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your example wouldn't work. Try surrounding your column names with [brackets] instead of "quotes".

```
select * from  t1
INNER JOIN t2 on t1.[Account Key] = t2.[Account Key]
INNER JOIN t3 on t2.[Account Key] = t3.[Account Key]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I did that and I also tried "set quoted identifier on", but I still have the same problem. :(

Comment: @Juan - Are the column names correct? Is that your actual query? More information may be required to answer your question.

Comment: My query is the same as shown in my question except for the table names. The table names are actually views that do a simple select to the original table. The purpose of the views are to give the column more human names (e.g.: [Account Key] instead of [acctky]). But my query does use a column named [Account Key].

Comment: Oh Wait! the t3 view's [Account Key] is actually a computed column: CAST(bid AS varchar(5)) + '-' + dbo.ConvertNumericToPaddedChar(RMKEY, 20). Would that make a difference?